# Backing up Configuration Server Azure Site Recovery

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

I am in the process of setting up Azure Site Recovery (ASR) for a vmware on-premise environment, however I'm a bit baffled regarding how to back up the Configuration server. I assume in the event of a major incident the Configuration server (based on-premise) would be lost, so a backup would need to be restored, however would it be possible to backup the configuration server to Azure using ASR, considering it does the ASR backups? Or do we need to have a separate backup method\process for the configuration server

Thanks in advance and apologies if this a abit of a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASR cannot be leveraged to backup Configuration Server (CS) to Azure. However, you can use Azure backup to backup CS to Azure.

Comment: when you creat a backup of the on premise server, do you need to use MARS to do files and folders or can you backup a snapshot of the server?

Comment: Depends on what you want to backup. If the intent is only to backup files and folders, MARS agent need to be installed on the on premise server. If you want to backup the whole server, you can use MABS.